# Assign word count value to a variable

Tags: bash, sh

I have over 100 files. I want to find lines with a certain value, wc those lines and get the Total word count from all the files. I am not sure how to assign a value to the word count. This is what I have but it gives error saying bad substitution.

```
total=0
for f in filename* 
  do
  currentFileCount=${grep "Cost\":25" $f | wc -l} 
  let total+=currentFileCount
done
echo $total
```

Comment: The bad substitution comes from the ${..}, you should use either back ticks or $(...)

Comment: Save the kitties, use `$( )` form :)

Comment: Is it `JSON` ??

Comment: @GillesQuenot No its not JSON.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Simply run :

```
totalcount=$(grep -c 'Cost":25' <(cat filename*))
echo $totalcount
```

But if it's some JSON, there's some better way to do it, with [jq](/questions/tagged/jq)

### If you prefer *pure bash*, use the proper `$( )` syntax :

```
total=0
for f in filename*; do
  currentFileCount=$(grep 'Cost":25"' "$f" | wc -l)
  total+=currentFileCount
done
echo $total
```

### And the less RAM consumer AFAIK :

```
awk '/Cost":25/{total++}END{print total}' filename*
```

Comment: Thanks. Wondering will using cat in this instance take up a lot of resource. Each of those files are close to 1GB in size.

Comment: As you can notice, there's a concatenation with a glob, so my code _just works_, test it if you're not sure

Comment: Sorry @GillesQuenot, missed that. +1